# Parse with lubridate R

Tags: r, parsing, lubridate

Dataset has column Connect.Time with the following structure:

```
$ Connect.Time      : chr  "7/11/2015 5:53 AM"
```

With lubridate package I change it to date with the hours & minutes mentioned. This code doesn't work and returns NA

```
W$Connect.Time <- as.Date(W$Connect.Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

This gives me "2015-07-11" but R doesn't show the hours and minutes. When trying to extract them hour(W$Connect.Time) it'll give me 0
I'm not sure what to do with the AM/PM either. 
How to correctly parse it with lubridate package? I want to be able to calculate duration of WiFi sessions in minutes

Comment: `as.Date` is not a lubridate function, but a base R. The lubridate function  `dmy_hm(x)` works well.

Comment: dmy_hm(x) works well indeed. Just ignore the AM/PM notations then?

Comment: @Diederik, as I showed in my answer the lubridate function does not ignore the AM and PM, it just recognize them all and does the proper conversion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `as.POSIXct()`. But in order to get the AM/PM correct you will need to use `%I:%M` for hours and minutes instead of `%H:%M`, as `%H` does not work with `%p` (the symbol for AM/PM).  Note they must be caps, as well.

```
## July 11, 2015 5:53 am
as.POSIXct("7/11/2015 5:53 AM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
# [1] "2015-07-11 05:53:00 PDT"

## July 11, 2015 5:53 pm
as.POSIXct("7/11/2015 5:53 PM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
# [1] "2015-07-11 17:53:00 PDT"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `lubridate` you have to parse it with:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "7/11/2015 5:53 AM"
dmy_hm(x)
[1] "2015-11-07 05:53:00 UTC"
```

The package is smart enough to recognize the `AM` and `PM` in your data, so do not worry about that. See the code:

```
y <- "7/11/2015 5:53 PM"
dmy_hm(y)
[1] "2015-11-07 17:53:00 UTC"
```

A thing that might be of your concern if the `tz` argument to set the right time zone.